# How to scrape links from website using selenium webdriver - python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

HTML content for scraping the links:

```
<div _ngcontent-mp-widget-c15 class="ng-star-inserted">
    <!---->
    <!---->
 <div _ngcontent-mp-widget-c15 class="list-item" id="list-item-16">
      <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-mp-widget-c15 class="content-details">
        <!---->
        <!---->
      <h2 _ngcontent-mp-widget-c15 class="ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-mp-widget-c15 angulartics2on="click" angularticsaction="expanded-detail" color="primary" href="/xyz-man/event/in-person/open-awesome-gardens">Open: Awesome Gardens</a>
      </h2>
      <!---->
      <!---->
```

I am using selenium webdriver for this and trying with the below code, but not getting the expected links:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://someurl.com")
lnk=[]
for a in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ng-star-inserted'):
    link = a.get_attribute('href')
    lnk.append(link)
print(lnk)
```

Comment: maybe you can use beautiful soup, that will allow you to filter by tag, id, and so on.

Comment: Unable to work with BeautifulSoup, becuase Id are not constant.